# System.getProperty("user.name") returns "?"

Tags: java

I am trying to use `System.getProperty("user.name")` in my Java Code to get the username for the web services. Somehow it is returning "?" (Question Mark)

What can be the main issue?

If someone calls services do we need to pass the username from the service instead of using system properties?

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.name");` returns the system property for `user.name`. Thus, if we started the program with `java -Duser.name="foobar" ...`, this call would return `"foobar"`.

Comment: Do you get proper value when you execute `java -XshowSettings:properties -version
` ?

Comment: The values returned by most properties are operating system-dependent. Perhaps you have some security settings prohibiting access to whatever or wherever Java tries to acquire the value for `user.name` from.

Comment: When I run locally, I get username value but after deployment, it is not showing anything.

Comment: What device do you deploy the program to?

Comment: Thanks, @Oliver, How I can change that setting?

Comment: @dan1st I deployed to the OCP platform.

Comment: @a.p.patel What is OCP? What OS is it running? Is the application in a container, such as Tomcat? Is it an applet?

Comment: OCP = RedHat OpenShift Container Platform, basically a kubernetes-ish thing.   Chances are good it's a privilege/protection issue.

Comment: @user16632363 Is there any way I can configure that?

Comment: Sorry, all I know about OCP is to answer "it's a privilege issue" - the default protections seem to be tighter than on other kubernetes providers.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by reading that username?

Answer (score 4):

Java has to read the name user it is currently running under from the OS environment. If the OS environment doesn't provide a name for that user, it sets the `user.name` property to "?" on Unix-like systems and to "unknown" on Windows systems.

The code fragment on [Unix systems](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.base/unix/native/libjava/java_props_md.c#L484)  is:

```
    struct passwd *pwent = getpwuid(getuid());
    sprops.user_name = pwent ? strdup(pwent->pw_name) : "?";
```

and on [Windows systems](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.base/windows/native/libjava/java_props_md.c#L632) it is:

```
    // ... various variants to try to read the user name
    // followed by
        sprops.user_name = (uname != NULL) ? uname : L"unknown";
```

---

If your code runs in a container, the container defines the uid that is used to run your code.

If the system that runs the container doesn't have a user name for that uid (or if the system or the container runtime doesn't allow to access the user name from within the container) then this is what you will see.